# JavaScript cross browser window close issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have this code here:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_GET['bd'])){
?>

<script>
    window.close();
</script>


<?php

}
```

Which is working okay in Chrome, but not working in FireFox.
Is there a known issue with this?
How can I get it to work consistently across the mentioned browsers?

Comment: Do you see an error in the Javascript Console?

Comment: try `<script type="text/javascript">window.close();
</script>`

Comment: @mgraph Browsers have long ago figured to expect javascript in `<script>`. In fact, it settles the problem whether to use `text/javascript`, `application/javascript` or something else...

Comment: Is the window you're closing, a pop-up window or other way created child element?

Comment: Then you cannot close that window!

Answer (score 8):

In most browsers, `window.close()` will only work if the `window` in question has an `opener`.
By an `opener`, I mean that you have a `parent` `window` that opens a `child` `window`. Only the `child` `window` can be closed by a `window.close()`.

Comment: No, the php condition has nothing to do with it. It depends on the origination point of the window. IF the window IS a child window then, I could forsee an issue with the php condition.

Answer (score 4):

For Firefox, the authoritative reference is MDN. A quote from there:

*This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.*

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close

As your webpage was constructed serverside and opened regularly, not by javascript, it won't work in your case.

Note also different behaviour in Internet Explorer:

*Invoking the window.close method on a window not opened with script displays a confirmation dialog box. Using script to close the last running instance of Windows Internet Explorer also opens the confirmation dialog box.*

So this will work, but with a confirmation.

Finally, I tested it on Opera and it works even on regularly opened windows, just like you said it does in Chrome.

Comment: @user1244193 Come on, did you even read my answer? According to MDN, which is basically Firefox's documentation, the reaction should be "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.". And that is precisely what my Firefox says. Have a look at Tools->Error console (Ctrl+shift+J).

Comment: Timestamp: 30/06/33 06:25:43 م
Warning: XUL box for _moz_generated_content_after element contained an inline #text child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block.
Source File: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line: 0 i got this what that mean

Comment: Eh, just to have it complete - I forgot to add the source for MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536367(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user1244193 That looks like a CSS error. You're looking for JavaScript errors...

Comment: ok it is tab window if i change it to pop-up window is something make change

Comment: @user1244193 Well, what can I say... you should be. But whether you can or can not find the error in the console, doesn't matter. You simply can't do that on Firefox. Consider opening the page by JavaScript, then requesting data from PHP by Ajax. This way it will be possible to close the window.

Comment: @user1244193 According to docs, no. But you can try that for yourself.

Comment: can i get the id from while loop whith ajax requesting

Comment: @user1244193 If you have more questions, you should just post them as questions.